# Meaning of subscription_id in android CallLog

Tags: java, android, calllog

I'm receiving call logs using

```
Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

in my andorid app. With `managedCursor.getColumnNames()` you get an overview over provided columns. There is one column called `subscription_id`. What is the meaning of it?

Answer (score 0):

Subscription id means the SIM card slot in which was the SIM card called from/to on the device.

You can get by:

```
int subscriptionId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("subscription_id"));
```

This value starts with 0 - means SIM card slot 1.

Comment: Actually it's not officially as such: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls#PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID , yet on some devices it's indeed the SIM card slot index. Wrote about this here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/73769425/878126