# Identifying a SIM card slot with PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID in Android CallLogCalls

Tags: java, android, kotlin, calllog

In dual-SIM card mobiles I manage to differentiate SIM cards in the calllog using the PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID property as shown in the code below. Now I need to know what SIM card actually was use (1 or 2) to make or receive the call. PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID shows something like this 8953011201104578086F for and one SIM card and similar, but no equal to the other. This was tested in a Samsung mobile:

```
fun readCallLog() {
    val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC")
    val number = cursor?.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER)
    val date = cursor?.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE)
    val type = cursor?.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)
    val account_id = cursor?.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID)


    val tmp : MutableList<List<String?>> = mutableListOf()

    while (cursor?.moveToNext() == true ) {
        val call_number = if (number != null) cursor.getString(number) else ""
        val call_date = if(date != null) cursor.getString(date) else ""
        val call_type = if(type != null) cursor.getInt(type).toString() else ""
        val call_account_id = if(account_id != null) cursor.getString(account_id) else ""

        tmp.add( listOf(call_number, call_date, call_type, call_account_id))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get information on SIM cards with `SubscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList()`.

On some devices, `Call.PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID` equals `subscriptionInfo.getSubscriptionId()`, however on other devices (your case) `subscriptionInfo.getIccId()` is a substring of it, so you need to check both.

See also [SubscriptionManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager) reference.

Answer (score 0):

The official way is to check the account-id (documentation [**here**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls#PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID)), but on some devices it just returns the SIM card slot index, so here's the code with a workaround (from [Android 6.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Marshmallow) (Marshmallow)):

```
fun getSimSlotIndexFromAccountId(context: Context, accountIdToFind: String): Int {
    // This is actually the official data that should be found, as on the emulator, but sadly not all phones return here a proper value
    val telecomManager = context.getSystemService<TelecomManager>()
    telecomManager.callCapablePhoneAccounts.forEachIndexed { index, account: PhoneAccountHandle ->
        val phoneAccount: PhoneAccount = telecomManager.getPhoneAccount(account)
        val accountId: String = phoneAccount.accountHandle
            .id
        if (accountIdToFind == accountId) {
            return index
        }
    }
    accountIdToFind.toIntOrNull()?.let {
        if (it >= 0)
            return it
    }
    return -1
}
```

Usage:

```
val simIdColumnIndex = callLogCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID)
val accountId: String = callLogCursor.getString(simIdColumnIndex)
val simCardSlotIndex = getSimSlotIndexFromAccountId(applicationContext, accountId)
```

I've reported about this issue (that some devices don't follow official API) here:

*[Bug: on some devices, PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID just returns the SIM-card slot index](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/247339277)*